# Hot to change the suffix of the test class generated by swagger codegen?

Tags: spring-boot, testing, swagger, pom.xml, swagger-codegen

I'm working on a Spring Boot application, and I use swagger-codegen for the first time to generate my controllers, and my controller test classes. I found how to modify the controller name (using the attribute "tag" in my swagger.yml), but not the controller Test class. Did I miss something? Is there a pom tag, or something to change the suffix of the generated test class? For now, the name of the class is like: "FooControllerIntegrationTest", but I want it to be called "FooControllerTest".

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Which codegen target do you generate? (the `-l` option of codegen CLI)

Comment: I'm not sure... I'm using a maven profile to configure the codegen. I think the answer you're waiting for is "spring". Does it make sense?

Comment: `<language>spring</language>` then?

Comment: Yes, that's it!